# Why is tomcat going to 200+ threads with Spring WebFlux?

Tags: tomcat, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am doing a POC with Spring WebFlux on Tomcat. The stack is totally reactive and using Spring Reactor and Reactive Couchbase.

When I added load on the System, I saw that the number of threads in JVisualVM increased to 200+. Basically, **reactor-http** threads were limited, about 4 as expected.

But **http-nio-exec** threads jumped to around 200. 
If I run with Netty instead of Tomcat the the number of threads is limited about 30 only.

Can some one explain why Tomcat is spinning up so many threads with a Reactive Stack?

Answer (score 8):

Because netty has implemented an event loop mechanizm that alows for efficient handoff of incomming connections. Tomcat still uses model one thread per request.

This is a pretty intreting article on the issue:

https://kamilszymanski.github.io/resources-utilization-in-reactive-services/